# Database Internals: How are variable size fields handled?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

Variable size fields seem like they could cause performance issue.

For the sake of being concrete, let's assume we're using a relational database. Suppose a relation has a variable length text field. What happens if an update to a tuple in the relation increases the variable length field's size? An in-line record edit (i.e. editing the file containing the record in-line) would require shuffling around the other tuples residing on the same physical page -- potentially kicking some out.

I understand that different DBMSs handle this differently, but I'm curious what some of the common practices are for this. It seems to me that the best way to do this would be to simply mark the existing tuple as deleted and create a whole new tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It depends". Each implementation is different and practically warrants its own small book. (I should really be close-voting this question not answering it, but I figure I'll try to help and I can't make this short enough for a comment).

---

For PostgreSQL, read [the developer documentation about DB storage and `VARLENA`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage.html), [storage classes and `TOAST`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html), as well as [the manual section on MVCC and concurrency control](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/mvcc.html). For more info, start reading the code, many of the key headers and source files have good detailed comments that explain the low level operation.

The condensed version, which you may have to read the above-mentioned resources to understand:

PostgreSQL never overwrites a tuple during an update. It always writes it to a new location. If the location is on the same physical page and there are no indexes changed it avoids index updates, but it'll always do a heap write of a new tuple. It sets the xmax value of the old tuple  and the xmin of the new one so that a transaction can only ever see one or the other. See the concurrency and mvcc docs for the gory details.

Variable length values may be stored inline or out-of-line (TOAST). If it's stored inline in the tuple on the heap, which is the default for small values, then when you update the record (whether you update that field or some other) the data gets copied to a new tuple, just like fixed length data does. If it's stored out-of-line in a TOAST side-table then if it's unmodified a pointer to it is copied but the value its self isn't. If it's stored out-of-line and modified then a new record is written to the TOAST table for that value and a new pointer to it is stored in the newly saved heap tuple for the new value.

Later on, VACUUM comes along and marks obsolete tuples, freeing space and allowing them to be overwritten.

Because PostgreSQL must retain the old data to be visible to old transactions it can never do an in-place modification.

In theory it'd be possible to put the old data somewhere else and then overwrite it - that's what Oracle does, with its undo and redo logs - but that's not what PostgreSQL does. Doing that introduces different complexities and trade-offs, solving problems and creating others.

(The only exception to the no-overwrite rule is pg_largeobject, which uses a sort of slice based copy-on-write to allow transactional updates to big file-like chunks of data without copying the whole file. Oh, and you could argue that `SEQUENCE`s get overwritten too. Also some full-table-lock operations.)

---

Other RDBMses work in different ways. Some even support multiple modes. MySQL for example uses MyISAM tables (in-place writes, AFAIK) and InnoDB (MVCC copy-on-write). Oracle has the undo and redo logs - it copies the old data to out-of-line storage then does an in-place update. Other DBMSes are no doubt different again.

Comment: " It sets the xmin value of the old tuple and the xmax of the new one". Transaction will set the xmax value of old and xmin of new, right?

Comment: @Jayadevan Er.. yeah. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL, there is some information about that in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-character.html:

> Tip: There is no performance difference among these three types [varchar(n)/character varying(n), char(n)/charachter(n), text], apart from increased storage space when using the blank-padded type, and a few extra CPU cycles to check the length when storing into a length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance advantages in some other database systems, there is no such advantage in PostgreSQL; in fact character(n) is usually the slowest of the three because of its additional storage costs. In most situations text or character varying should be used instead.

I would assume that "an in-line record edit" will never occur, due to data integrity requirements and transaction processing (MVCC).

There is some (fairly old) information about transaction processing:
http://www.postgresql.org/files/developer/transactions.pdf

> We must store multiple versions of every row. A tuple can be removed only after it’s been committed as deleted for long enough that no active transaction can see it anymore.